# passing values to another file using shell script

Tags: shell

I would like to create a shell script file such that it gets certain values from a .dat or excel .xls file then pass these values to another file as in the following example;

1-The .dat value has 32x5 matrix size;Example

```
1 3 4 5 6
4 5 7 9 8
:
:
1 1 1 2 4
```

2-.geo file has the following

```
x1= ;
x2= ;
x3= ;
x4= ;
x5= ;
```

I would like to create 32 geo file with each row of the .dat or .xls file e.g.
1.geo has;

```
x1 = 1;
x2 = 3;
x3 = 4;
x4 = 5;
x5 = 6;
```

2.geo has the second row etc.

In summary, shell script loop through the rows and pass them to the geo file and save it with different geo file name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? `while read -r line; do...` with a prior `declare -i count` would work.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! I actually tried with the files that come with DAKOTA but it didn't work with me. If you could provide an example of your idea that would be appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: Note the answer is POSIX shell compliant. If you have an advanced shell like bash, you have options to use arrays. You can also use a *heredoc* instead of `printf` in either case. `awk` also provides an easy solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your exercise is actually simply handled by reading each line into separate variable, e.g. `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d` and `$e`. Once read, you can write them out in into separate `$count.geo` files (e.g. `1.geo`, `2.geo`, ...) in the format you desire with `printf`. A simple implementation would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

dat=${1:-geo.dat}   ## .dat filename ('geo.dat' default)
count=1

test -r "$dat" || { ## validate input file is readable
    printf "error: file not readable '%s'\n" "$dat"
    exit 1
}

while read -r a b c d e; do     ## read each value into a b c d e
    printf "x1 = %d;\nx2 = %d;\nx3 = %d;\nx4 = %d;\nx5 = %d;\n" \
    $a $b $c $d $e >$count.geo
    ((count++))
done <"$dat"
```

Using `awk`, you could use a one-liner similar to:

```
awk '{printf "x1 = %d;\nx2 = %d;\nx3 = %d;\nx4 = %d;\nx5 = %d;\n", \
$1, $2, $3, $4, $5 > FNR".geo"}' geo.dat
```

**Example Input File** `geo.dat`

```
$ cat geo.dat
5 9 4 4 2
8 4 3 8 7
5 8 4 3 7
1 3 9 8 2
5 8 2 2 1
7 1 8 3 4
3 7 4 7 2
5 6 6 9 5
3 4 4 8 6
2 9 9 1 7
2 6 5 4 8
5 1 9 4 3
4 6 1 7 5
2 4 1 7 3
6 2 6 1 9
3 3 9 3 4
6 5 9 2 8
8 7 8 8 2
1 2 9 1 1
4 3 5 5 1
8 2 2 5 3
2 7 5 1 1
9 6 5 9 8
4 9 6 2 8
8 3 1 7 4
2 1 6 7 7
7 5 9 9 9
2 3 7 8 3
9 8 1 5 7
9 9 7 6 1
6 4 5 7 2
8 9 3 6 6
```

**Example Use**

```
$ sh readgoedat.sh geo.dat
```

or

```
$ awk '{printf "x1 = %d;\nx2 = %d;\nx3 = %d;\nx4 = %d;\nx5 = %d;\n", \
$1, $2, $3, $4, $5 > FNR".geo"}' geo.dat
```

**Example Output Files**

```
$ cat 1.geo
x1 = 5;
x2 = 9;
x3 = 4;
x4 = 4;
x5 = 2;

$ cat 2.geo
x1 = 8;
x2 = 4;
x3 = 3;
x4 = 8;
x5 = 7;

$ cat 32.geo
x1 = 8;
x2 = 9;
x3 = 3;
x4 = 6;
x5 = 6;
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: God bless Mr. Rankin! Printing the values  into 1.geo....32.geo is prefect. However, in my case, I have all .geo file ready from 1,...32 except that I only need to put x1, x2, x3, x4, and x5 into each existing geo file. Here is an example of one of the .geo file.

Comment: /*//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
D = 1.02; //
x1 = 0.1;//
x2 = 0.06;//
x3 = 0.51;//
t11 = 1;//
x4 = -0.02;//
x5 = 1.1;//
Lt = 0;
detn = 0.4;
detd = 0.44;
c1n = 2;
c2n = 4;
c3n = 5;
c1d = 4;
c2d = 6;
c3d = 4;
/*//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
If (e == 30)
         y = 1.2e-3;//
EndIf
If (e == 50)
         y = 2.1e-3;//
EndIf
If (e == 70)
         y = 2.9e-3;
EndIf
// 
Point(1) = {-7.5*D, 10*D, 0, 0};

Comment: The problem now is that it prints the value into the existing geo files but it removes the rest of the values.  Many thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm still confused. "*except that I only need to put x1, x2, x3, x4, and x5 into each existing geo file*" Are you saying that if a `.geo` file already exists, don't make a new `#.geo` file?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. What you showed earlier is perfect. However, if I have an existing .geo file, say for example, grid.geo and I want to pass the values of 1.geo to grid.geo and saved as a grid1.geo. Knowing that grid.geo has already other values that should be kept.Similarly, 2.geo pass it to grid.geo and saved as grid2.geo etc. I hope that this is clear. Many thanks again!

Comment: You just need to add a `[ -f "$count.geo" ]` to test if `"$count.geo"` already exists, if it does, then write to `"$count.geo1"`. You can do it in a loop to check and increment a counter to make sure you get a unique filename, e.g. `if [ -f "$count.geo" ]; then n=1; while [ -f "$count.geo$n" ]; do ((n++)); done; fi` and then write to `"$count.geo$n"`. Many ways to skin that cat. You can search "*bash get unique filename*" (or similar) to find many examples.

Comment: I am going to just to do them manually and call it a day. Thanks anyway!